# How To Display Sub Category On Sub Category Pages

Tags: magento-1.9

How To Display Sub Categories On Sub Categories Pages . For Example I have categories Like

```
1) HIS
 - Wallets
 -  Belts

2) HER 
 - Wallets
 - Nighty
 - Handbag
```

When the user selects the wallets all the sub categories should be shown on the left

[image]

Comment: Do you have sub category of "wallet"? Can you show your full admin category screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getChildrenCategories()->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Comment: Please, explain more details.